# share assets beetween platforms

Tags: libgdx, assets

What is the good way to share assets between platforms (android, desktop, etc) ?

by default there is an assets folder in each platform folder.

Comment: find some clue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433012/how-do-i-link-assets-from-android-to-desktop-in-libgdx

Comment: if you think that might be the answer for the question, feel free to write an answer that includes also the content of the link, so that if the link gets unavaiable/broken, people will still know how to solve a similar problem. Comments are used to ask more details for the question, not to answer it.

Comment: They all use the assets folder from the android project. You don't need to care about any other asset folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plebiscited and usual way is to use the android asset folder for all other platforms

ie for desktop:

Click Run -> Edit configurations..., then change the "Working directory" parameter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433012/how-do-i-link-assets-from-android-to-desktop-in-libgdx